# Incorrect path to save the file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload, django-media

I am now getting the file from my front-end and I set my model like this.

model.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image= models.FileField(upload_to='image/', default=None)
    intro= models.FileField(upload_to='info/', default=None)
```

view.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LsRequestSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['post']
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = User
         field = '__all__'

     def create(self, validated_data):
         newUser = User.objects.create(
             name = validated_data['name']
             image = validated_date['image']
             intro = validated_date['intro']
         )
         return newUser
```

However, when I did the HTTP.POST in Postman, it gave the wrong path to save the image.

```
"http://localhost:8000/media/Koala.jpg"
```

But based on my design in the model with path_to, it should give:

```
"http://localhost:8000/media/image/Koala.jpg"
```

Update: 
    The strange thing is that when I tried to update a user by giving a new image using HTTP.Patch method, it then has the right path.

Update:
    It turns out to be the problem that I cannot have multiple input filefield and upload_to different subfolders. How to solve this problem?
    If I put the serializer as above, it can find the right path but it also means that these two fields are required. But in fact, these two fields are optional. 
    But if I put the if statement outside the create function, it cannot detect the correct path. 
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
             model = User
             field = '**all**'

```
     def create(self, validated_data):
         newUser = User.objects.create(
             name = validated_data['name']
             image = None
             intro = None
         )
         if validate_data['image']:
            newUser.image = validate_data['image']
         if validate_data['intro']:
            newUser.image = validate_data['intro']
         return newUser
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should first check that if you specified the right path for media in your `setting.py` it should be something like this:

The place that you want to store those pictures:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

And as you want to see them like `"http://localhost:8000/media/whatever/whatever.jpg"` you should specified the `MEDIA_URL` like this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And then as you did it in your models the argument will be like:

```
upload_to='image/'
```

You can also read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url)!

And as a side note if you want to deal with pictures then you can use `ImageField` rather than `FileField`.

Comment: I did set up these params in my setting.py and it turned out to be the other problem. So right now I have two different fields which both of them are fileField but the input of them are optional, which means it can be none. But I cannot right an if statement outside the create object otherwise it cannot find the right path. Do you have any idea of this problem ?

Comment: You probably have to add `newUser.save()` after changing it.

Comment: Excellent if it was helpful you can vote up and accept the answer.